# AnyLogic: Writing data from an excel file to a table function

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to create a simulation that involves data on weather throughout a year. I've got the data in an excel spreadsheet and I'm trying to write it to a table function to use to change some dynamic variables for each day.

I've been trying to use `int readTableFunction(TableFunction tableFunction, String sheetName, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, int length)` from the anylogic help page but I can't put it in the table function or dynamic variable so the only place I could try was the main agent's on startup box.

the excel file is just 'weather' and then the table function is 'rainTF'
the cells I need data from are A2:A366 and K2:K366

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a simulation that involves data on weather throughout a year. I've got the data in an excel spreadsheet and I'm trying to write it to a table function to use to change some dynamic variables for each day.

Don't. This is not how you should use table functions. Load the data into the model database and query it from there